# ffmpeg in C++ "av_register_all not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile this simple program in C++ (in Code Blocks):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
    #endif
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

However I keep getting the error message:
|11|error: ‘av_register_all’ was not declared in this scope|

Other people seem to have had this problem and adding the `extern "C"` section seems to have solved it form them but not me. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Did you set up your additional libraries / additional include files?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466856/how-to-use-ffmpeg-with-msvc-to-decode-a-video/17471424#17471424) you can find how to do it in MSVC++, I have used CodeBlocks a little & never included an external library to it, however I think you should be able to adopt it to CodeBlocks.