# how to use ffmpeg with MSVC++ to decode a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, decode

What i want to do is to make a sample application using msvc++ which will take input as a video file and decode it. I want all the decoding to be done using ffmpeg functions used in my application.I read dranger's tutorial but could not implement it, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. **you can build the source code yourself.**
2. **you can download an "already builded version" with dlls.**

If I were you, I would have chosen the second option. It was what I have had done when I started to experiencing with ffmpeg. Building can be a pain if you have never built a source code.

You can find latest ffmpeg builds from   [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (You should download the "dev" version).

Put this file inside **VisualStudio20xx/Projects/yourProjectName/yourProjectName/**

After downloading you should show MSVC the destination of headers & the .lib files.
Go to 
Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General
then set the "Additional Include Directories" to ffmpeg/include

This should set the include files for ffmpeg.

For .lib files:

Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General
set "Additional Library Directories" to ffmpeg/lib

This should set the .lib files.

Now should be able to include ffmpeg libraries by

```
extern "C" 
{
     #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}
```

*(!) **If you get a thousands of LNK2001 linker errors** after these steps, you should add some pragma comments for your includes. I am not %100 sure what do these comments do, you can search it. But it is something for MSVC to understand stuff.

For example,

```
#pragma comment (lib,"avcodec.lib")
```

this pragma comment too, should be in extern "C" scope.

*(!)If you get this compile error : **'UINT64_C': identifier not found**

You can use this macro as a workaround:

```
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
```

Now about the encode/decode stuff, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470153/how-to-extract-elementary-video-from-mp4-using-ffmpeg-programmatically) question of mine which contains a code that

1. demuxes the file into packets
2. decodes the packets into frames
3. encodes the frames into packages
4. muxes packets into a file.

I learnt from hard way but the code is well-commented therefore I think you can understand what/how exactly it does to overcome the process.